# Why is this not saving to the database?

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel

I'm trying to save a new product into the database, this product has exportation factors which i'm also trying to save, why is this not working?

```
 if ($request->has('export_factors')) {
    $exportationFactors = [];

    foreach ($request->get('export_factors') as $item) {
        if (key_exists('country_id', $item)) {
            $export = ExportationFactor::where('country_id', $item['country_id'])->first();
        } else if (key_exists('fi', $item)) {
            $export = ExportationFactor::where('fi', $item['fi'])->first();
        } else if (key_exists('margin', $item)) {
            $export = ExportationFactor::where('margin', $item['margin'])->first();
        }

        $export->save();

        $exportationFactors[] = [
            "product_id" => $export->product_id,
             "country_id" => $export->country_id,
             "fi" => $export->fi,
             "margin" => $export->margin
        ];

        if (count($exportationFactors) > 0) {
            ExportationFactor::insert($exportationFactors);
        }

    }
}
```

The error i'm getting is:

> Call to a member function save() on null

on line `$export->save();`

Comment: `$export` is `null`. Dump it and check its content.

Comment: because export return null.

Comment: Because `$export` is `null` from your query.

Comment: Probably neither one of these key exists, since you didn't set anything to do on `else`

Comment: Maybe this will help... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35988648/call-to-a-member-function-save-on-null-laravel

Comment: No @LucasArbex if that was the case, it would be `undefined variable $export` error.

Comment: @ChinLeung indeed, rookie mistake.

Comment: add an if(!empty($export){$export->save();}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the insert outside the loop for performance, and dont do a save on something that's not there

```php
$product_id = //you need to fill this one.
if ($request->has('export_factors')) {
    $exportationFactors = [];

    foreach ($request->get('export_factors') as $item) {
        $country_id = $item['country_id']??null;
        $fi = $item['fi']??null;
        $margin = $item['margin']??null;
        if (isset($fi, $margin, $country_id) {
            $exportationFactors[] = [
                "product_id" => $product_id,
                "country_id" => $country_id,
                "fi" => $fi,
                "margin" => $margin,
            ];
        }
    }
    if (count($exportationFactors)) {
        ExportationFactor::insert($exportationFactors);
    }
}
```

Comment: would this also work for an update function, to update the exportation factors?

Comment: @NancyGomez if you want to do an update, you need an id with the other attributes. take a look at the method `updateOrCreate`. For mass update or insert, you will need to builde your query without eloquent models using `INSERT...ON DUPPLICATE UPDATE....`

Answer (score 1):

It's possible there is a route through your code when `$export` isn't set (if it doesn't match any of the `key_exists()` tests).

Either this is an error and it should be set to something - or you should check if it's set before saving...

```
// Check if export is needed
if ( !empty($export) )  {
    $export->save();

    $exportationFactors[] = [
        "product_id" => $export->product_id,
         "country_id" => $export->country_id,
         "fi" => $export->fi,
         "margin" => $export->margin
    ];

    if (count($exportationFactors) > 0) {
        ExportationFactor::insert($exportationFactors);
    }
}
```

You should also make sure that you reset the value each time in the loop, as it may have the value left over from the previous loop...

```
foreach ($request->get('export_factors') as $item) {
    unset($export);
```